# Incorrect number of rows with Two Inner Joins that count related records

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query where I select animals at a particular level along with some information about their species...

```
SELECT animals.id, animals.name, species.name, species.exlevel
FROM `animals` 
INNER JOIN species ON animals.spid = species.id
WHERE animal.level=1
```

I am trying to append this query to include a count of all comments from the comments table left for each animal. However, I can't find the optimal way to do it. The following obviously doesn't work but is what I am looking to do... without doing two separate queries.

```
SELECT animals.id, animals.name, species.name, species.exlevel, COUNT(comments.id)
FROM `animals` 
INNER JOIN species ON animals.spid = species.id
INNER JOIN comments ON animals.id = comments.anid
WHERE animal.level =1
AND comments.type =2
```

Comment: And what's wrong with doing two separate queries?

Comment: They are not as efficient... Because I loop through the mysql_fetch_array from the current query and then do a select query to count for comments. I want to move to just one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT animals.id, animals.name, species.name, species.exlevel, COUNT(comments.id)
FROM `animals` 
INNER JOIN species ON animals.spid = species.id
LEFT JOIN comments ON animals.id = comments.anid AND comments.type =2
WHERE animal.level =1
GROUP BY animals.id, animals.name, species.name, species.exlevel
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked... but I grouped on just the animals.id field.